# OctoberCMS - How to redirect user to home after email confirmation from user plugin?

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am using User Plugin in octobercms. Currently it is set to activation by email and user is directed to signup page with code. It actually signs in user after activation but it shows signup page. User have to go to login page and then to his id. Is there a way I can modify activation link to login instead of signup. Or to home directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the redirect parameter to the configuration section of the page here you define the component:

```
[account]
redirect = "/dashboard"
paramCode = "code"
==
{% component 'account' %}
```

See the [user plugin github repo](https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin) for more info. Search for redirect.